# Testing what a player says

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I would like to make a minecraft map where command blocks say would you like to go to lava parkour? Then if you say yes it will tp you if you so no nothing happens. I was thinking it's probably a /testfor @p/say"yes" or something I'm in the latest snapshot it is probably no something possible but I would like to try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something little input together with the `/tellraw` command. All you have to do is click on `Teleport?` when the message shows up in chat. Here's the command:

```
/tellraw @a {"text":"","extra":[{"text":"Would you like to teleport?","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/tp @a <x> <y> <z>"},"hoverEvent":{"action":"show_text","value":"Teleport?"}}]}
```

Remember to replace `<x> <y> <z>` with the specific coordinate values. You can also add colors to the text, but I'll let you figure that one out. **Note:** In order for this message to appear in chat, the command block containing it **must** be activated in some way. Anyways, hope this helps!
 **Note** I haven't had time to fully test this yet, so tell me if something is wrong. Thanks!
 **Another note:** If players are required to be an OP, switch their gamemodes to creative, then after they teleport back to survival.

Comment: This will require that the person getting the message have permission to teleport themselves, won't it?

Comment: @BillyMailman I'm pretty sure players in survival, if commands are enabled, are able to teleport themselves without requiring OP.

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms seeing that `/tp` requires `op-permission-level` of 2 or more, non-OPs surely can't. Trigger-type objectives can be used (or are meant to be used) for exactly this kind of thing.

Comment: @MrLemon  this is a single player map im making

Comment: @kingbluesapphire Just because it's singleplayer, there a level-based restrictions on which players can use certain commands. For example, in order to summon in mobs, you must be in creative mode with cheats on.

Answer (score 2):

Building on DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms' Answer (and stealing his json for tellraw), you can use `trigger` to circumvent needing OP permissions to teleport on click. They have to be enabled for a player (done via commandblock), who can then use the `/trigger` command to modify his score once, then the trigger is disabled again.

#### Tutorial

Set up a trigger objective (once) using

```
/scoreboard objective add <name> trigger
```

Use two command blocks with

```
/scoreboard players enable <player> <name>
/tellraw @a {"text":"","extra":[{"text":"Would you like to teleport?","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/trigger <name> set 1"},"hoverEvent":{"action":"show_text","value":"Teleport?"}}]}
```

The teleport itself is done via a command-block hooked to a clock, using

```
/tp @a[score_<name>_min=1] <x> <y> <z>
```

Replace all values in `<>` with the appropriate values.

Comment: Thanks for adding on some info to this, I didn't realize OP was needed until now.

Comment: Also, you just reached 1000 reputation! Congrats!